# delimit string in tcl/tk (\b), doesn't it work?

Tags: tcl, pcre

good morning, i am having trouble using string delimitation in tcl, the scape character '\b' does not work, could someone help me?
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
switch -regexp -matchvar ds $arg_dns {
     \-([aut]?)d([aut]?) {
          puts "achou $ds"        
     }
}
```

Comment: You probably should write `{\-([aut]?)d([aut]?)}` in there; the rule of thumb is (almost) always put REs in braces in Tcl in order to avoid problems with excess backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be expecting the PCRE syntax, where [`\b` is a word boundary](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#smallassertions). In Tcl's RE syntax (which uses a totally different engine), [the equivalent is `\y`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M72) (as `\b` instead matches a backspace character).